# When setting winform panel name by reflection, setting visible to true fails. Why?

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection

I am attempting to loop through a number of panels which have .Visible = false set by default.  I want to change these to true, but I will only know which ones at run time.

I have the following code:

```
var genericPanel =  new Panel();
            var myName = "panel" + i;
            PropertyInfo prop = genericPanel.GetType().GetProperty("Name", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
            if (null != prop && prop.CanWrite)
            {
                prop.SetValue(genericPanel, myName, null);
            }

            genericPanel.Enabled = true;
            genericPanel.Visible = true;
            var blah = genericPanel.Name;  // Name is correct
            Application.DoEvents();

            // This works fine
            //panel1.Visible = true;
            //panel1.Enabled = true;
            //Application.DoEvents();
```

Using reflection I appear to be able to set the object name correctly, but my attempts at setting the visibility and enabled properties fail.  Doing so directly works just fine.

What am I missing?

Comment: Where have you added the Panel?

Comment: The panel is inside a groupbox which is on the main application.

Comment: I'm not good at Reflection, but I don't see where you set genericPanel to an existing Panel. All I see is you create it (why?) and set its (meaningless) Name property.

Comment: Note that a variable's name has (pretty much) nothing to do the a Control's `Name` property. The only direct connection is that the designer sets the `Name` to be the same as the control's name. But you can change it anytime and it can be empty as well as non-unique.. (Look at the property tab: There is no `Name` property there but a field '(Name)' only.. - And the method [`Control.ControlCollection.Find`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) returns: An array!!

Comment: TaW - I simply misunderstood what it was doing.

Comment: No wonder, the Control.Name property has confused many folks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you need to use `System.Reflection` for that. You're creating new panel inside your code which is wrong. You should do the following:

```
private void SetControlVisibility(string controlName, bool visible)
{
    // Searches through all controls inside your Form recursively by controlName
    Control control = GetControlByName(this.Controls, controlName);

    if (control != null)
        control.Visible = visible;
}

private Control GetControlByName(Control.ControlCollection controls, string controlName)
{
    Control controlToFind = null;

    foreach (Control control in controls)
    {
        // If control is container like panel or groupBox, look inside it's child controls
        if (control.HasChildren)
        {
            controlToFind = GetControlByName(control.Controls, controlName);

            // If control is found inside child controls, break the loop
            // and return the control
            if (controlToFind != null)
                break;
        }

        // If current control name is the name you're searching for, set control we're
        // searching for to that control, break the loop and return the control
        if (control.Name == controlName)
        {
            controlToFind = control;
            break;
        }
    }

    return controlToFind;
}
```

**Use case example:**

```
int i = 3;
string controlName= "panel" + i; // I'm hiding green panel (panel3)
SetControlVisibility(controlName, false);
```

**Before:**

[image: Before]

**After:**

[image: After]

**EDIT:**

As suggested in comments, you can also use `Find` method of `Control.ControlCollection`. It would look like this:

```
// True flag is to search through all nested child controls
Control[] controls = this.Controls.Find(panelName, true);
if (controls != null)
    controls[0].Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the panel to the form's (or some container) controls.

You probably already have a panel1 which is confusing you:

```
var genericPanel = new Panel();
var myName = "panel" + 3;
PropertyInfo prop = genericPanel.GetType().GetProperty("Name", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
if (null != prop && prop.CanWrite)
{
    prop.SetValue(genericPanel, myName, null);
}
genericPanel.Enabled = true;
genericPanel.Visible = true;
genericPanel.BackColor = Color.Red;

this.Controls.Add(genericPanel);
```

Comment: I made sure I don't have other panels with the same name.   Either using "this" or the name of the groupbox they are inside does not set them to visible.   These panels already exist btw if it wasn't clear in my description.